# package: LATTICE --> Histogram FUNction LABEL

Tags: r, label, histogram, lattice

I have successfully put together 3three Histograms into 1one Plot with the `Lattice` package.
My data and code is as follows:

```
Puma_301 
   [1] 15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15 
  [19] 15  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33 
  [37] 33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33 
  [55] 33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45 
  [73] 45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45  45 etc...
Levels: 15 33 45 51 52 55 56 57 60 65 80 83 84 92 96 105 112 113


Puma_302
  [1] 15 15 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 35 45 45 45 45 45
 [26] 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45
 [51] 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45
 [76] 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45
[101] 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 etc...
Levels: 15 33 35 45 51 52 56 65 92 95 96

Puma_303
  [1] 15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15 
 [19] 15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15 
 [37] 15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  15  33  33  33 
 [55] 33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33 
 [73] 33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  33  45 etc..
Levels: 15 33 45 51 52 56 57 60 65 80 83 84 92 93 96 105 112

histogram(~Puma_303 + Puma_302 + Puma_301, type='count', layout=c(1,3), 
    main='Histograms of GPS points by Vegetation Types')
```

When I plot the 3three histograms at the very bottom of the plot appears the label

> Puma_303 + Puma_302 + Puma_301

I have not been successful in finding a method to get rid of the bottom label.

Does anybody know how 'histogram()' can change the label into something else or not even show the label?

Thanks

p.s.  I tried uploading the image of the plot but since I am a new user I am not allowed. sorry!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy one, you just need 'xlab'

histogram(~Puma_303 + Puma_302 + Puma_301, type='count', layout=c(1,3),main='Histograms of GPS points by Vegetation Types', xlab="My xlab")

Also, ' xlab= "" ' will remove the axis label altogether (have spaced that out for clarity).

Worked for me. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks nzcoops... removing the axis label worked.  Easy indeed!